# Android .write to .csv-file, file gets created but no text is saved

Tags: android, csv, bluetooth, writer

I have an android application that collects data from a sensor via Bluetooth.

When trying to save the data to a .csv-file on the device, the **data.csv**-file gets created but no text is saved in the file.

The function in question:

```
private void writeData(boolean writeError) {
    try {
        File traceFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), writeError ? "error.csv" : "data.csv");
        if (!traceFile.exists())
            traceFile.createNewFile();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(traceFile, true /*append*/));

        writer.write("Test string");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

No error is thrown and I've made sure that each part of the code gets executed. Any ideas as to why this doesn't work?

Comment: You need to `flush()` and `close()` the writer.

Comment: This worked thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Solution by [Hurundi V. Bakshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2649012/hrundi-v-bakshi)

Added

```
writer.flush();
```

after

```
writer.write("Test string");
```

Documentation on *flush()*:

> [Flushes this writer. Implementations of this method should ensure that all buffered characters are written to the target.](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Writer.html#flush())